# Ensure Order of query in MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have `100M` records(consisting of `user_unique_id`, `transaction_id` and some other fields) indexed with `user_unique_id` and `transaction_id` and among them `100` belongs to me(records which have user_unique_id as my user_unique_id), now I wanted to write a query where in input array I have some `90` of them(`transaction_id's`) and `10` are not there, now my job is to fetch those 10.

Now in order to perform this query what I can do is

**Process a**. First I will search for my 100 docs in 100M records using my user_unique_id index So scanned docs will be equal to 100 only. Then I can use `$arrayElemAt` to see if the element is present in my 90 of the records or not and if not then I will return that record.

**Process b**. First I will use `$arrayElemAt` to find if that record is present in my 90 of the records and if not present then I will search in the 100M records.

Now if I will perform `Process b` then does `transaction_id` index will get utilise or not because for every document we will have to see `$arrayElemAt` so I think scanned docs will be 100M.

Can anyone please tell me do both Steps ensure that I will search my 100 records first using `user_unique_id` and then use `$arrayElemAt` to see if the document is present or not ?? Because as MongoDB itself perform [query-optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/) how will the final decision be made?

**Step 1**

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                { /* Search In 100M record using user_unique_id */},
                { /* USe $arrayElemAt to look if that  record is present or not */},
            ]
        }
    }
]);
```

**Step 2**

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        { /* Search In 100M record using user_unique_id */},
    }
},
{
    $match: {
        { /* USe $arrayElemAt to look if that record is present or not */},
    }
}
]);
```

`Indexes` present in transactions.

```
> db.transactions.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "application.transactions"
        },
        {
            "v" : 2,
            "unique" : true,
            "key" : {
                    "transaction_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "transaction_id_1",
            "background" : true,
            "ns" : "application.transactions"
        },
        {
            "v" : 2,
            "unique" : true,
            "key" : {
                    "user_unique_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "user_unique_id_1",
            "ns" : "application.transactions",
            "background" : true
        }
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your information, MongoDB should process the both queries (`Step1` and `Step2`) in the same way.

I think that MongoDB will use `user_unique_id_1` index because it will be smaller (so it will be faster).

MongoDB first selects documents by `user_unique_id` field, then will checks other conditions.

MongoDB is smart enough to select best (the most efective/fastest) plan for query execution, so the `winning plan` sometimes can be different according to the details of the collection and query.

If you want to check which is `winningPlan` of your query, then just add the `{ explain: true }` option to your `aggregation` query.

Example:

```
db.transactions.aggregate([...], {explain: true});
```

Take a look into [`explain` documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) page.

Comment: But the thing is there is also an index on `transaction_id`? WIll it work all cases ?

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur can you show the result of `db.transactions.getIndexes()` ?

Comment: I have added in my post, please have a relook :)

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur I updated my answer. I think that MongoDB will choose `user_unique_id_1` index, because it will be smaller  (less possible values than `transaction_id_1`). Actually everything depends on your acctual data, so I recomending you to check the explain results of your queries.

Comment: transaction_id's will be at least around 10 times the user user_unique_id's.

Comment: So there is no way for me to decide which step to perform first, all depends on MongoDB then ??

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur MongoDB choose the fastest execution plan. For that it runs all possible plans (each use a different index) in parallel and choose the fastest plan.

Comment: Actually when I am trying to add explain with aggregation I am getting this error `throw new Error('Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators');`

Comment: I also tried to use mongoose-explain but it is also not working.